# Hadoop namenode format

Tags: java, hadoop

I followed link : http://sundersinghc.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/running-hadoop-on-cygwin-in-windows-single-node-cluster/

When formatting namenode I am facing this issue below:

> $ ./hadoop namenode -format
>   DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
>
> $ ./hdfs namenode -format
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

I have checked all configuration files and hadoop classpath along with JAR everything is OK.

I tried it on both hadoop-2.2 and hadoop-2.4 as well with Java 7

Please help

Thanks,

Manoj

Comment: maybe this link helps: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution. It suggest to run `bin/hdfs namenode -format` from `$HADOOP_HOME`.

Comment: I switch to Ubuntu and my problem was resloved